# Unexpected EntityObject Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, edmx, business-logic-layer

I have the following code:

```
public IList<T_CLIENT> Get_All_Obj()
{
    try
    {
        IList<T_CLIENT> LesListe;
        using (FaExpedEntities oEntite_T = new FaExpedEntities())
        {
            var query = from o in oEntite_T.T_CLIENT select o;
            LesListe = query.ToList();
        }
        return LesListe;
    }
    catch (Exception excThrown)
    {
        throw new Exception("Err_02", excThrown);
    }
}
```

But I don't know why I get these errors:

```
Error 1 The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject'is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089'. C: \ Soft8 \ FA_Exped \ Code \ FrontEnd \ FaExped_FrontEnd_WebApp_Domaine \ FaExped_FrontEnd_WebApp_Business \ Le_T \ LeTclientusrstatus_Entite_BL.cs 15 42 FaExped_FrontEnd_WebApp_Business

Error 2 c: \ Soft8 \ FA_Exped \ Code \ FrontEnd \ FaExped_FrontEnd_WebSite \ Login.aspx.cs (8): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'FaExped_FrontEnd_WebApp_Business' not found (a using directive or a reference to 'assembly is it missing?)

Error 3 'FaExped_FrontEnd_WebApp_Domaine.FaExpedEntities': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'C: \ Soft8 \ FA_Exped \ Code \ FrontEnd \ FaExped_FrontEnd_WebApp_Domaine \ FaExped_FrontEnd_WebApp_Business \ Le_T \ LeTclient_Entite_BL.cs 22 17 FaExped_FrontEnd_WebApp_Business
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Is this on your developer machine or is it on another machine? have you made sure that System.Data.Entity is in your bin folder?

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a reference.

Comment: What is the structure of the solution?  Is the EF Data Model (EDMX) in another project than the one hosting the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this simply like so:

```
var entities = new FaExpedEntities();
return entities.T_CLIENT.ToList();
```

Make sure you have the necessary references and using statements.

Hope this helps :)